# what tense to use with 'until'

Tags: tense, adverbs

What verb tense to use with the adverbial clause 'until'?

for example

> I had been swimming until nine o'clock yesterday
>
> I swam until nine o'clock yesterday
>
> I was swimming until nine o'clock yesterday
>
> I had swum until nine o'clock yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You can use most tenses, except present continuous or present perfect.

> I swam until 9pm

> I was swimming until 9pm

even

> I had been swimming until 9pm

But past perfect is not for general use.

And in the future

> I will swim until 9pm

> I will be swimming until 9pm

You can use the present to talk about everyday activities

> Every day after work, I swim until 9pm

the difference between "swam" and "was swimming" is pretty minor. Just the usual implications of  a continuous, temporary, ongoing activity.